# Nested case sqlite query

Tags: python, sqlite, subquery, case

I've recently started my experience with sqlite and I have to create query in which I calculate total time (in hours) of all reservations in a given period in every hotel's room with given from_date and to_date.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT RoomId,
            CASE 
                WHEN CAST(strftime('%s', startsAt) As Integer) >= CAST(strftime('%s', ?) As Integer) 
                THEN
                   CASE WHEN CAST(strftime('%s', endsAt) As integer) >= CAST(strftime('%s', ?) As Integer) 
                     THEN Cast ((JulianDay(?) - JulianDay(?)) * 24 As Integer)
                   ELSE Cast ((JulianDay(endsAt) - JulianDay(?)) * 24 As Integer)
                   END
            ELSE
                CASE 
                  WHEN strftime('%s', endsAt) >= strftime('%s', ?) THEN
                     THEN Cast ((JulianDay(?) - JulianDay(startsAt)) * 24 As Integer)
                ELSE Cast ((JulianDay(endsAt) - JulianDay(?)) * 24 As Integer)
                END
            END Time
        FROM Reservation """, (from_date, to_date, to_date, from_date, from_date, to_date, to_date))
```

Can you tell me what I have been doing wrong?

Comment: I count 8 `?` and 7 parameters. Perhaps have a look at using [named placeholders](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute).

Comment: Thank you very much, this way is much easier!